# Sorting a list using the quicksort algorithm in Game Maker Studio 2

Tags: sorting, quicksort, game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

I am working with Game Maker Studio 2.3.6 to sort the list of character speeds on screen in descending order with an iterative algorithm (bubble sort). However, I plan to have a lot of on-screen characters for some of the battles. Therefore, I considered switching to the quicksort algorithm to reduce run time.

Here is the simple iterative algorithm I currently use to sort the speed values (written in GML).

```
function bubble_sort(list){
    list_size = ds_list_size(list);
    for (var i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < list_size - i - 1; j++) {
            if (list[|j].current[@SPEED] < list[|j+1].current[@SPEED]) {
                var swapped = list[|j];
                list[|j] = list[|j+1];
                list[|j+1] = swapped;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I defined the speed values using macros.

```
#macro SPEED 0
base[SPEED] = 10;
current[SPEED] = base[@SPEED];
```

When I call my bubble sort function, I use `global.units` as an argument which is a list that contains the IDs of all the mobs that have been spawned. Through `global.units`, one can access their speed with `.current[@SPEED]` for a j-th mob as you can see in the bubble sorting algorithm above.

I wrote a quicksort algorithm. Below are the partition and the function itself.

```
function partition(list, low, high){

    var pivot = list[high]; // point de pivot autour duquel il faut modifier la liste
    var i = low;

    for (j = low + 1; j <= high; j++) {
        if (list[j] > pivot) {
            i++;
    
            // on fait pivoter la liste en i et la liste en j
            swapped = list[i];
            list[@i] = list[j];
            list[@j] = swapped;
        }
    }

    // on fait pivoter la liste en i+1 avec la plus haute valeur
    swapped = list[i];
    list[@i] = list[high];
    list[@high] = swapped;

    return i;
}
```

In a different script,

```
function quicksort(list, low, high) {
    if (low < high) {
        partition_ref = partition(list, low, high); // on partitionne l'indice

        // on trie les éléments de manière récursive avant et après la phase de partition des éléments
        quicksort(list, low, partition_ref);
        quicksort(list, partition_ref + 1, high);
    }
}
```

After a lot of head-scratching, I could not work out how I can implement the SPEED macro into my quicksort algorithm. Perhaps this is one of those problems with obvious answers, but which I cannot see.

Could anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general options related to utilizing what's already is in the language (and is written in native code rather than slightly-slower GML) are:

- Use `array_sort` with a custom comparator function
- Put subjects of interest into a `ds_grid` along with their "score" and use `ds_grid_sort`
- Put `(score << 32) | id` in a ds_list and use `ds_list_sort` (if the source list/array contains structs, use an index inside that instead).

As for your quicksort, `var pivot = list[high]` and `if (list[j] > pivot) {` would need to account for the item's score (speed) rather than getting/comparing it "as is".